# Set image by commit

Tags: git, continuous-integration, commit, git-commit

I'm developoing some code that outputs a processed image. 
Sometimes the result is good sometimes not, but this doesn't mean that the code is not useful.

Is there a way of saving an image in the commit message => then you can checkout the commit where you know the nature of the result

Or any similar solution?

I have tried checkingout each commit then compile and get the image, or commit the image itself. But this isn't as practical as having an "image history"

Comment: Simplest way is to do `xdate=$(date); git tag "image-is-good-$xdate" <commit ID>`.

Comment: But, I want to actually see the development of the image, not only a description of it

Comment: It isn't related to Git per se. CI has the facilities you are asking for. And it keeps it on a separate storage / data base. It has nothing to do with Git. (Git is just a source of the code)

Answer (score 0):

Git does not provide image or any sort of rich text functionalities in the commit message, only plain text.  Some hosting platforms do make assumptions about the content of commit message (e.g., that they are Markdown), and in those environments, you may be able to embed a suitable [data: URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and have it show up in that platform's UI.  However, Git itself and the tools that ship with it will not display the image.